# Messy photosets after changing to -500 on Tumblr

Tags: html, tumblr

I am using the "Copycat" theme on Tumblr (you can check my page [here](http://jeanclaudecourt.tumblr.com/)).

I want to change the Photoset-250 to Photoset-500.

```
      {block:Photoset}
            {block:IndexPage}
            {block:IfPhotosetOnlyFirst}
            <div class="photoset-note"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Photoset ({PhotoCount} images)</div>
            <figure class="photoset-content" width="{PhotoWidth-250}" height="{PhotoHeight-250}">

                {block:Photos}<a{block:IfPermalinkNewWindow} target="_blank"{/block:IfPermalinkNewWindow} href="{Permalink}"><img class="photo-post-photo" src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-retina="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></a>{/block:Photos}

            </figure>
            {/block:IfPhotosetOnlyFirst}
            {block:IfNotPhotosetOnlyFirst}
            <figure class="photoset-content">{Photoset-250}</figure>
            {/block:IfNotPhotosetOnlyFirst}
            {/block:IndexPage}

            {block:IfIndexPhotoCaptions}
            {block:IndexPage}
            {block:Caption}
                <div class="post-content"><figcaption>{Caption}</figcaption></div>
            {/block:Caption}
            {/block:IndexPage}
            {/block:IfIndexPhotoCaptions}

            {block:PermalinkPage}
                <div class="post-content">
                <figure class="photoset-content">{Photoset}</figure>
                {block:Caption}<figcaption>{Caption}</figcaption>{/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:PermalinkPage}
        {/block:Photoset}
```

The resolution of the pics improve; but the photosets don't load properly. There are big spaces among them; and there are some photosets that don't load at all.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hey Jean, you can (and should) post your code directly in your question. Copy and paste it, then select it and click the `{}` button of the editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You see: you should never ever take screen shots of **code**. Code is text, and as Barthy suggests, you have to have your code as **text** in your question!

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. I have edited my message. Sorry for the code thing, I didn´t know it.

Comment: Could someone please help me?